# How to plot multiple dataframes with different lenghts into one plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

### The question

I have a lot of dataframes (approx. 300) that I would like to plot into one line chart. The issue is, they all have different a number of values (i.e. lengths). How can I plot the data frames such that they all start and end at the same point (on the x-axis) in the figure?

I can convert data frames to lists or series or whatsoever.

### Example

- df1: `[5, 3, 10, 7, 10...]`
- df2: `[2, 4, 5, 7, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1]`
- adjusted df2: that desired state - same len as df1

```
df1 df2 adjusted df2
5   2   2
3       2
10      2
7   4   4
10      4
5       4
8   6   6
6       6
5       6
6   7   7
2       7
1       7
5   2   2
3       2
6       2
9   1   1
9       1
7       1
10  3   3
2       3
7       3
7   0   0
6       0
1       0
6   1   1
9       1
```

### Example with datetimes

```py
                datetime       value
5448 2020-01-19 22:05:00  166.300003
5449 2020-01-19 22:10:00  165.259995
5450 2020-01-19 22:15:00  164.699997
5451 2020-01-19 22:20:00  165.380005
5452 2020-01-19 22:25:00  166.179993
5453 2020-01-19 22:30:00  162.630005
5424 2020-01-19 22:35:00  162.550003
5425 2020-01-19 22:40:00  161.990005
5426 2020-01-19 22:45:00  161.750000
5427 2020-01-10 22:50:00  161.440002
```

```py
                 datetime       value
15900 2020-02-25 11:55:00  262.510010
15901 2020-02-25 12:00:00  263.179993
15902 2020-02-25 12:05:00  262.260010
15903 2020-02-25 12:10:00  261.959991
15904 2020-02-25 12:15:00  262.179993
15905 2020-02-25 12:20:00  261.299988
15906 2020-02-25 12:25:00  261.579987
15907 2020-02-25 12:30:00  261.890015
15908 2020-02-25 12:35:00  262.820007
15909 2020-02-25 12:40:00  262.010010
15910 2020-02-25 12:45:00  261.630005
15911 2020-02-25 12:50:00  261.109985
15912 2020-02-25 12:55:00  261.149994
15913 2020-02-25 13:00:00  260.679993
15914 2020-02-25 13:05:00  261.929993
15915 2020-02-25 13:10:00  260.880005
15916 2020-02-25 13:15:00  259.929993
```

```py
                 datetime       value
16407 2020-02-27 06:10:00  224.860001
16408 2020-02-27 06:15:00  224.240005
16409 2020-02-27 06:20:00  223.610001
16410 2020-02-27 06:25:00  223.490005
16411 2020-02-27 06:30:00  223.199997
```

So the plot will look like this
[image]

### Possible options

#### 1. Interpolate values

The idea is similar to the example above, but I am not sure how to "shift the values" so that the data frame lengths will match.

#### 2. Use a different x-axis for each data frame

Not sure how exactly to do this yet.

Comment: If the dates and times don't line up, what are you basing the alignment on?

Comment: thats the issue - date and times are not aligned... I just need to see all possible ranges inside one chart and every range needs fit 100% of the chart width - as shown on the example. It is because I wanted to see if there is any pattern in tha data (e.g. last values are always decreasing etc.)

Comment: I've updated my solution now that I understand your actual problem. The new method does not make up any data between points, though matplotlib will linearly connect points together when plotting a line.

Comment: thanks jared, it seems likes thats the solution of my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated Answer

After you've clarified the problem in your question and comments, you're actual intention is not to combine the datasets but to simply plot the datasets such that the first and last points match up. This can easily be done by creating an `x` array for each data frame that goes from 0 to 1 but has the N points, where N is the length of the data frame; I did this using `np.linspace`.

Shown below is the code and plots for the original and time series data. Since you want to see the trends, for the time series data I subtracted each of them by the first value so they all start at 0.

Using the original data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.close("all")

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"data": [5, 3, 10, 7, 10, 5, 8, 6, 5, 6, 2, 1, 5, 3, 6, 9, 9, 9, 7, 10, 2, 7, 7, 6, 1, 6, 9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"data": [2, 4, 6, 7, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, df in enumerate([df1, df2], start=1):
    x = np.linspace(0, 1, len(df))
    ax.plot(x, df["data"], label=f"df{i}")
ax.legend()
fig.show()
```

[image]

Using the time-series data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.close("all")

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"datetime": ["2020-01-19 22:05:00",
                                 "2020-01-19 22:10:00",
                                 "2020-01-19 22:15:00",
                                 "2020-01-19 22:20:00",
                                 "2020-01-19 22:25:00",
                                 "2020-01-19 22:30:00",
                                 "2020-01-19 22:35:00",
                                 "2020-01-19 22:40:00",
                                 "2020-01-19 22:45:00",
                                 "2020-01-10 22:50:00",],
                    "value": [166.300003,
                              165.259995,
                              164.699997,
                              165.380005,
                              166.179993,
                              162.630005,
                              162.550003,
                              161.990005,
                              161.750000,
                              161.440002,
                              ]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"datetime": ["2020-02-25 11:55:00",
                                 "2020-02-25 12:00:00",
                                 "2020-02-25 12:05:00",
                                 "2020-02-25 12:10:00",
                                 "2020-02-25 12:15:00",
                                 "2020-02-25 12:20:00",
                                 "2020-02-25 12:25:00",
                                 "2020-02-25 12:30:00",
                                 "2020-02-25 12:35:00",
                                 "2020-02-25 12:40:00",
                                 "2020-02-25 12:45:00",
                                 "2020-02-25 12:50:00",
                                 "2020-02-25 12:55:00",
                                 "2020-02-25 13:00:00",
                                 "2020-02-25 13:05:00",
                                 "2020-02-25 13:10:00",
                                 "2020-02-25 13:15:00",],
                    "value": [262.510010,
                              263.179993,
                              262.260010,
                              261.959991,
                              262.179993,
                              261.299988,
                              261.579987,
                              261.890015,
                              262.820007,
                              262.010010,
                              261.630005,
                              261.109985,
                              261.149994,
                              260.679993,
                              261.929993,
                              260.880005,
                              259.929993,]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"datetime": ["2020-02-27 06:10:00",
                                 "2020-02-27 06:15:00",
                                 "2020-02-27 06:20:00",
                                 "2020-02-27 06:25:00",
                                 "2020-02-27 06:30:00",],
                    "value": [224.860001,
                              224.240005,
                              223.610001,
                              223.490005,
                              223.199997,]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, df in enumerate([df1, df2, df3], start=1):
    x = np.linspace(0, 1, len(df))
    ax.plot(x, df["value"] - df["value"].iloc[0], label=f"df{i}")
ax.legend()
fig.show()
```

[image]

---

### Original Answer

Although I think this is not the right way to deal with your data, I will show you how to do what you ask.

Before we implement any of the methods, you will need to combine the data with the alignment you showed. To do this, you can reindex `df2` in steps of `len(df1)/len(df2)`. I do this using the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"df1": [5, 3, 10, 7, 10, 5, 8, 6, 5, 6, 2, 1, 5, 3, 6, 9, 9, 9, 7, 10, 2, 7, 7, 6, 1, 6, 9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"df2": [2, 4, 6, 7, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1]})
df2.index = np.arange(0, len(df1), len(df1)//len(df2))
```

The two DataFrames can then be joined on the `index` column using this next line.

```py
df_combined = df1.join(df2, how="outer")
```

So, after those two steps, we have `df_combined`.

```py
    df1  df2
0     5  2.0
1     3  NaN
2    10  NaN
3     7  4.0
4    10  NaN
5     5  NaN
6     8  6.0
7     6  NaN
8     5  NaN
9     6  7.0
10    2  NaN
11    1  NaN
12    5  2.0
13    3  NaN
14    6  NaN
15    9  1.0
16    9  NaN
17    9  NaN
18    7  3.0
19   10  NaN
20    2  NaN
21    7  0.0
22    7  NaN
23    6  NaN
24    1  1.0
25    6  NaN
26    9  NaN
```

Note: Because `NaN`s were added, the `df2` column is now `dtype=float`.

You seem to mention two methods, filling `df2` with the data with the same value and interpolating. For filling, you can simply call the `ffill()` method, which will forward-fill `NaN`s, i.e. if the value is `2` before a `NaN`, it will fill that in with a `2`.

```py
df_combined["df2_ffill"] = df_combined["df2"].ffill()
```

To interpolate, you can call the `interpolate()` method, which, by default, will linearly interpolate the `NaN`s based on the values before and after the `NaN` (or group of `NaN`s).

```py
df_combined["df2_interpolate"] = df_combined["df2"].interpolate()
```

So, we have `df_combined`:

```py
    df1  df2  df2_ffill  df2_interpolate
0     5  2.0        2.0         2.000000
1     3  NaN        2.0         2.666667
2    10  NaN        2.0         3.333333
3     7  4.0        4.0         4.000000
4    10  NaN        4.0         4.666667
5     5  NaN        4.0         5.333333
6     8  6.0        6.0         6.000000
7     6  NaN        6.0         6.333333
8     5  NaN        6.0         6.666667
9     6  7.0        7.0         7.000000
10    2  NaN        7.0         5.333333
11    1  NaN        7.0         3.666667
12    5  2.0        2.0         2.000000
13    3  NaN        2.0         1.666667
14    6  NaN        2.0         1.333333
15    9  1.0        1.0         1.000000
16    9  NaN        1.0         1.666667
17    9  NaN        1.0         2.333333
18    7  3.0        3.0         3.000000
19   10  NaN        3.0         2.000000
20    2  NaN        3.0         1.000000
21    7  0.0        0.0         0.000000
22    7  NaN        0.0         0.333333
23    6  NaN        0.0         0.666667
24    1  1.0        1.0         1.000000
25    6  NaN        1.0         1.000000
26    9  NaN        1.0         1.000000
```

Here is the data plotted:

[image]

Now, as I said in the beginning, this is not the best way to deal with the data because there is no "right" way to make up data. The best thing to do is what you mention last, which is to plot against some other variable; the DataFrame index is not a good option to plot against because it has no meaning.

Assuming this data is some dependent data, i.e. it was computed or derived by some process, there is probably an independent variable associated with it. Maybe it's time, such as seconds, days, or years, or it's distance, such as feet, meters, or miles. That is what you should actually plot against. If you have that information for `df1` and `df2`, then plotting each against the corresponding independent data will line up the graphs properly and you wouldn't have to combine them and make up data.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. I have datetime for each value. But I am not sure how to apply the method you mention or even what do you mean exactly. Thanks jared.

Comment: @FN_ that is very important information. You should add that to your post.

Comment: How it's gonna affect the solution? thx

Comment: @FN_ Because that's the independent variable you should actually be plotting against. As I said, these filling techniques are bad techniques to use because you're making up data.

Comment: @FN_ If you share the datetime data then I might be able to show you the right way to do this.

Comment: thanks jared, I have adjusted the question and added more (real one) examples

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that the index/x values have no meaning for the individual dataframes.
Then you can normalize the indices via the `MinMaxScaler` and plot them like this into a single plot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16)*np.random.random(16)) # length 16
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(7)*np.random.random(7)) 
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(2)*np.random.random(2)) # length 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for df in [df1,df2, df3]:
    df = df.copy()
    df.index =  MinMaxScaler().fit_transform( df.index.values.reshape((-1,1))).flatten() )
    df.plot(ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = [5, 3, 10, 7, 10]
df2 = [2, 4, 5, 7, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3]

arr1 = []
for i in range(len(df1)):
    arr1.append([i,df1[i]])
    
arr1 = np.array(arr1, dtype='int')
x1 = arr1[:,0]
y1 = arr1[:,1]

arr2 = []
for j in range(len(df2)):
    arr2.append([j,df2[j]])
    
arr2 = np.array(arr2, dtype='int')
x2 = arr2[:,0]
y2 = arr2[:,1]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,4))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(x1,y1, color='red')
ax1.plot(x2,y2, color='blue')
plt.xlabel('Index')
ax1.legend(["Serie A", "Serie B"], loc ="upper right")
plt.title('Seria A and Serie B', loc='left', color='grey')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you just want to make them same size:

If you already have pandas dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
import math

# generate sample data
adf = pd.DataFrame({"df1" : [5,3,10,7,10,5,8,6,5,6,2,1,5,3,6,9,9,9,7,10,2,7,7,6,1,6,9]})
bdf = pd.DataFrame({"df2" : [2,4,6,7,2,1,3,0,1]})

# add the bdf values to adf dataframe
adf['bdf'] = [bdf['df2'].iloc[math.floor(i/len(adf.df1)*len(bdf.df2))] for i in range(len(adf.df1))]

adf
#Out[3]: 
#    df1  bdf
#0     5    2
#1     3    2
#2    10    2
#3     7    4
#4    10    4
#5     5    4
#6     8    6
#7     6    6
#8     5    6
#9     6    7
#10    2    7
#11    1    7
#12    5    2
#13    3    2
#14    6    2
#15    9    1
#16    9    1
#17    9    1
#18    7    3
#19   10    3
#20    2    3
#21    7    0
#22    7    0
#23    6    0
#24    1    1
#25    6    1
#26    9    1
```

If you have just a list of values:

```
a = [5,3,10,7,10,5,8,6,5,6,2,1,5,3,6,9,9,9,7,10,2,7,7,6,1,6,9]
b = [2,4,6,7,2,1,3,0,1]
b_adjusted = [b[math.floor(i/len(a)*len(b))] for i in range(len(a))]
b_adjusted
#Out[5]: 
#[2,
# 2,
# 2,
# 4,
# 4,
# 4,
# 6,
# 6,
# 6,
# 7,
# 7,
# 7,
# 2,
# 2,
# 2,
# 1,
# 1,
# 1,
# 3,
# 3,
# 3,
# 0,
# 0,
# 0,
# 1,
# 1,
# 1]
```